# Get information from a file piped into a C program from terminal

Tags: c

A file that has a bunch of numbers in it will get piped into the program:

```
./executable < file.txt
```

I need to store the contents of that file in a dynamically allocated int pointer array, and search it for the highest number.  I used `fgets()`, but that is working with chars and not ints.

Is there any way to do this?

Here was the code to get input, but that did not really work as I want it to:

```
#define MAX 100                                                                 
                                                                                   
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                
   {                                                                               
       int i;                                                                      
       char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);                                  
       fgets(buffer, MAX, stdin);                                                    
   }
```

Edit: I tried this, but it displays values as 0.  (The file has exactly 24 numbers in, each on a new line, with no spaces after them)

```
 #include <stdio.h>                                                              
 #include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                         
 #define MAX 24                                                                  
                                                                                  
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                
 {                                                                               
      int i, *ptr;                                                                
      int *values = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);                                    
      ptr = &values[0];                                                           
                                                                                  
      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {                                                 
          scanf("%d", &ptr);                                                      
          ptr++;                                                                  
      }                                                                           
                                                                                   
      ptr = &values[0];                                                           
      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {                                                 
          printf("%d\n", *(ptr + i));                                             
      }                                                                           
                                                                                   
      free(values);                                                               
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                        
}
```

I will try  `fread` now and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: use `fread` instead. But passing binary data via `stdin` might be not a best idea

Comment: Read the data as text (supposing that matches the file), and *convert* them to numbers.  Depending on the details of the file format, that might be as simple as, say, running `scanf("%d", &one_number)` in a loop until its return value is different from 1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ah yes, I didn't noticed the `<`, I am closed to midnight ^^

Comment: "*in a dynamically allocated int pointer array*" so look at `realloc` to increase the size of the array of `int` where you save the read values each time it is necessary

Comment: @EugeneSh. not sure at all it is a binary file

Comment: @bruno Well, maybe I have over-analyzed the *"I used fgets(), but that is working with chars and not ints."* statement.

Comment: @EugeneSh. no problem, myself I didn't noticed the `<` redirecting input ^^

Comment: Note that the command line redirects the data into the program; it is not piped to the program.

Comment: Use `fread()` to read binary `int` values.  But you would probably do better with text data where you  could use `fgets()` or `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that you read into `&ptr`. `ptr` is a pointer to `int` so you need to read into it, not into its address.

The actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
 #include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                         
 #define MAX 24                                                                  
                                                                                  
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                
 {                                                                               
      int i, *ptr;                                                                
      int *values = malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);                                    
      ptr = values;                                                           
                                                                                  
      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {                                                 
          scanf("%d", ptr);                                                      
          ptr++;                                                                  
      }                                                                           
                                                                                   
      ptr = values;                                                           
      for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {                                                 
          printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);                                             
      }                                                                           
                                                                                   
      free(values);                                                               
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to C, I was used to putting & in scanf.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define INIT_MAX 5

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                
{                                                                               
    int size, total, run, i;
    int *values = malloc(sizeof(int) * INIT_MAX);
    int *ptr;
    size = INIT_MAX;
    total = 0;
    ptr = &values[0];

    run = scanf("%d", ptr);
    while (run == 1) {
        total += 1;
        ptr++;
        if (total > size - 3) {
            values = (int *) realloc(values, sizeof(int) * (size * 2));
            size *= 2;
            ptr = &values[total];
            if (values == NULL) {
                printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        run = scanf("%d", ptr);
     }
    
     ptr = &values[0];
     for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(ptr + i));
     }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;                                                        
}
```

Figuring out the realloc() was tricky, because I didn't realise that every time I reallocated the memory, my `int *ptr` would run into issues and mess everything up.